# How to encode text for an nlp in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, 32),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["acc"])

train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels = getdata()

model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)

print(results)
```

This is my basic tensorflow model and I have my datasets but I'm completely unsure on how to convert the strings in the data to something the network can take in as an input. I'm very new to TF btw.

Comment: You have to 'vectorize' the tokens. Essentially converting words to numerals.  There are a few techniques for that; count vectorizer, tf-idf vectorizer, etc... Have a look at this article: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/applied-text-analysis/9781491963036/ch04.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gensim library effective for text embedding without losing its meaning and sequence. An example code below. Feel free to make changes according to your needs. Choose algorithms, optimizers etc. as per your requirement.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Bidirectional, LSTM, Dense, GlobalMaxPool1D, Dropout
# first, we initialize a tokenizer which will convert text corpus to numbers (vectorization) 


reviews_text = ["list of strings you want to analyze"]

sentiment = <array of labels/target>

top_words = 1500
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=top_words)

# second, we update the vocabulary of the tokenizer by providing text
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(reviews_text) # fit on reviews before converting to matrix

# third, we transform each text into a sequence of integers
reviews_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(reviews_text)

len(tokenizer.word_index) # length of tokernizer, means unique words in the vocab

# in order for the math to work, we convert each review into same length. Padding...
max_len = 300
reviews_seq = pad_sequences(reviews_seq, maxlen=max_len)

# word2vec requires list of lists as input
documents = []
i = 0
for doc in <list of strings>:
  i += 1
  documents.append(doc.split(' '))
# gensim model training, it will translate a word into 128 numbers
embedding_size = 128
window_size = 128
w2v = Word2Vec(documents # input list of lists
               , min_count=3 # any word must appear 3 times or more for training
#                , workers=3 # CPU cores to be used for training the model
               , size=embedding_size # no. of numbers required to represent a word
               , window=window_size # how many neighbors to look at either side of the word for learning
               , iter=20 # no. of iterations over the documents for training
              )
w2v.wv.vectors.shape # shape of the model
# create embeddings to be added into keras model
embedding_matrix = zeros((top_words + 1, embedding_size))
# build matrix from pre-trained word to vec model
for word, i in sorted(tokenizer.word_index.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    if i > top_words:
        break
    if word in w2v.wv.vocab:
        embedding_vector = w2v.wv[word]
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words + 1, embedding_size, input_length=max_len, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

optimizer = Adadelta(learning_rate=0.001, rho=0.92)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(reviews_seq, asarray(sentiment), validation_split=0.2, epochs=1000, batch_size=32)
```